# IEnumerator<T>.Current beyond MoveNext() == false

Tags: c#, .net, iterator

I have a following code in my graph library:

```
while(true) {
    using (var i = ancestry.GetAdjacent(current).GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!i.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        if (i.MoveNext())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ancestry graph can only have one adjacent vertex for any given vertex");
        // it's a bug, as some enumerators could return null after failed MoveNext().
        current = i.Current;
        if (isSentinel(current))
            yield break;
    }
}
```

This code works for some instances of IEnumerator, and fails for others (all standard implementations from .NET, plus iterator methods with yield return.

Is that behaviour unspecified?

If not, what is the correct notation? Leave Current at previous, or set to default(T)?

UPDATE:

I have explored some of the implementations of IEnumerator for collections, Linq extensions as well as typed array: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zp30jD).

In my understanding, Linq violates the contract of IEnumerable, as it does not throw on Current beyond the end of enumeration, and typed array violates the contract of IEnumerable, as it throws on `IEnumerable<T>.Current`, and there are no exception types specified for IEnumerable.Current.

Can someone clarify, what does it mean 'undefined' when it's stated in documentation? Does it include throwing unspecified exceptions:

From [IEnumerator.Current Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58e146b7(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> Current is **undefined** under any of the following conditions: The
>   enumerator is positioned before the first element in the collection,
>   immediately after the enumerator is created. MoveNext must be called
>   to advance the enumerator to the first element of the collection
>   before reading the value of Current. The last call to MoveNext
>   returned false, which indicates the end of the collection. The
>   enumerator is invalidated due to changes made in the collection, such
>   as adding, modifying, or deleting elements. Current returns the same
>   object until MoveNext is called. MoveNext sets Current to the next
>   element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `Current` is not defined, if `MoveNext` returns `false`, as per the contract of the interface, as is described in its documentation.  You should never rely on any given behavior.  You simply shouldn't ever check the value of `Current` whenever `MoveNext` is `false`.

> If `MoveNext` passes the end of the collection, the enumerator is positioned after the last element in the collection and `MoveNext` returns `false`. When the enumerator is at this position, subsequent calls to `MoveNext` also return `false`. If the last call to `MoveNext` returned `false`, `Current` is undefined.

(Note that `IEnumerator` says that `Current` should throw an exception in this situation, but in my experience most implementations don't bother to explicitly throw, they just expose an undefined value; this change is reflected in the newer `IEnumerator<T>` interface's documentation.)

Comment: "they just expose an undefined value". What do you mean? Does it return null? Does it return a random value (such as the last value for .Current)? In my case, if not running any test against MovedNext was False, calling .Current would throw a KeyOutOfRangeException. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @Ama It means you don't know what it means.  You can't know if it will return null, a random value, throw an exception, or *literally anything else*.  That's the definition of being undefined.  Thus when providing your own implementation, *whatever you do, you've met the contract*.